# Python: click() function on xpath query result issue

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm having an issue trying to click on an `a href` tag from an xpath query, the line in question is `element = atag.xpath("./a")`, I get an error saying `Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import time
import os.path
import lxml.html as LH
import re
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from random import randint

PARAMS = sys.argv
URL = PARAMS[1]
BASEURL = URL[:URL.rfind('/')+1]

try:
    PAGE_NUMBER = 1

    #--------------------------------------------------
    ## Get initial page

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(PARAMS[1])

    #--------------------------------------------------
    ## Get page count

    # Give page time to load
    time.sleep(2)

    PAGE_RAW = driver.page_source
    PAGE_RAW = LH.fromstring(PAGE_RAW)
    PAGE_COUNT_RAW = PAGE_RAW.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'menu')]/div/ul/li")
    PAGE_COUNT = len(PAGE_COUNT_RAW) - 2

    #--------------------------------------------------
    ## Get page if it's not page one

    while PAGE_NUMBER <= PAGE_COUNT:
        #--------------------------------------------------
        # Delay page processing for a random number of seconds from 2-5
        time.sleep(randint(2,5))
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Create empty file
        FILE_NAME = PARAMS[3] + 'json/' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H") + '_' + str(PARAMS[2]) + '_' + str(PAGE_NUMBER) + '.json'
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Create JSON file if it doesn't exist
        if os.path.exists(FILE_NAME)==False:
            JSON_FILE = open(FILE_NAME, "a+", encoding="utf-8")
        else:
            JSON_FILE = open(FILE_NAME, "w", encoding="utf-8")
        JSON_FILE.write("{")
        #--------------------------------------------------
        # Click page for next page if not page 1
        if PAGE_NUMBER > 1:
            index = 1
            for atag in PAGE_COUNT_RAW:
                if index == (PAGE_NUMBER + 1):
                    element = atag.xpath("./a")
                    element.click()
                index += 1
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Proces page
        #TODO
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Close webdriver
        driver.quit()
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Close JSON file
        JSON_FILE.write("}")
        JSON_FILE.close()
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Increment page number
        PAGE_NUMBER += 1
        #--------------------------------------------------


except Exception as e:
    print('Error: ' + str(e.args[0]))
```

Comment: I don't do python but I think the problem is coming from you using `driver.page_source` instead of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()`. Is there some reason you went that route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed `lxml` code with `selenium` code. Your `element` is a list returned by `lxml` code, it's not a *WebElement* or *list of WebElements* and you can't apply `click()` even if you try `element[0].click()`.

I'd suggest you to avoid using `lxml` as it seem to be redundant in this case. Just try to parse page source with `selenium` built-in methods.

If you need to get list of `div` elements you can use:

```
PAGE_COUNT_RAW = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'menu')]/div/ul/li")
```

To find child `a` element:

```
for div in PAGE_COUNT_RAW:
    element = div.find_element_by_xpath('./a')
```

Note that if you defined `PAGE_COUNT_RAW` on the first page, **it will not be accessible on the next page**, so you can scrape just a list of links and then get each link in a loop. Something like:

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'menu')]/div/ul/li/a")]
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
```

If you need more details then update your ticket with specific description as for now your problem is not quite clear